# How to generate a table on select of a dropdown in Angular 8

Tags: arrays, angular, angular8

In my program, I've the table already rendered with all the given possible values. I only want to retrieve the values matching with my bookingId in the table.

***view.component.ts**

```js
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
        import { Booking } from '../booking.model';
        import { ViewService } from './view.service';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-view-component',
          templateUrl: './view-component.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./view-component.component.css']
        })
        export class ViewComponentComponent implements OnInit {
        
          bookings=[];
          selected: number;
          tableData:any[];
          selectedId:string='';
          constructor(private http: HttpClient, private view: ViewService) { }
        
        
          
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.getBookings();
           
          }
        
        
          getBookings(): void {
            this.view.getBookings()
            .subscribe((data:any) => {
              this.bookings = data;
              console.log(this.bookings);
            });
          }
        
          onSelected(value:string){
          console.log("the selected value is " + value);
        
          let temp =this.bookings.filter(el=>el.bookingId===value)
          console.log(temp);
          this.bookings=temp
        
         } 
     }
```

**view.component.html**

```html
<label for="bookings">
        Select a Booking Id
    </label>
    
    <select class="form-control" id="bookings" #mySelect 
    (change)='onSelected(mySelect.value)'>
    
    <option disabled selected value="">Select an Id</option>
    <option *ngFor="let book of bookings" [value]="book.bookingId">
            {{book.bookingId}}
    </option>
    </select>
    
    <table class="table table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Booking Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Booking Date</th>
    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let book of bookings">
                <td>{{book.bookingId}}</td>
                <td>{{book.guestName}}</td>
                <td>{{book.gender}}</td>
                <td>{{book.categoryName}}</td>
                <td>{{book.bookingDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The problem is the table is already generated by the time my application loads. I want it to generate on select of the appropriate dropdown. The dropdown is populated by Booking Ids. Can someone give a solution

Comment: looking at the code you have, the `onSelected` method is doing the jobs of filtering your existing list based on the value selected `this.bookings.filter(el=>el.bookingId===value)`. since you have your templated bound to the `bookings` property, change detection should kick in and pick up the changes. are you saying this change detection isn't working? or are you asking how to make the HTTP request to the service after the user has made a their choice via the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You binding same array in HTML use another empty array for filter data.
if you want first booking id data loaded when page render then just call onSelected(data[0].bookingId) after get data in getBookings()

```
filtersBookings = [];

onSelected(value:string){
  this.filtersBookings =this.bookings.filter(el=>el.bookingId===value)
} 
    
<tr *ngFor="let book of filtersBookings">
   <td>{{book.bookingId}}</td>
   <td>{{book.guestName}}</td>
   <td>{{book.gender}}</td>
   <td>{{book.categoryName}}</td>
   <td>{{book.bookingDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not load booking in ngOnInit hook, you should load it in your **onSelected** event handler,
and in your template, you can your the **ngIf** to load your table only when there is booking like the following

```html
<table class="table table-striped" *ngIf="bookings.length>0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Booking Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Booking Date</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let book of bookings">
            <td>{{book.bookingId}}</td>
            <td>{{book.guestName}}</td>
            <td>{{book.gender}}</td>
            <td>{{book.categoryName}}</td>
            <td>{{book.bookingDate| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```